# Mongo aggregation having two different counts

Tags: mongodb

I have such data (simplified):

```
{ "_id" : "1eh5mpr77l", 'user.id': "1eh5mq0qqx", "up" : 1, "down" : 0 } 
{ "_id" : "1eh5mprtc2", 'user.id': "1eh5mq0qqx", "up" : 1, "down" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "1eh5mpsfkn", 'user.id': "1eh5mq0qqx", "up" : 2, "down" : 1 }
```

I want to receive two integers: total count of records for some condition and total count of record having more complex condition. Is it possible to merge it in single query?

This aggregation finds me the total count:

```
db.comments.aggregate([{ $match: { 'user.id': "1e40v0b1j5"}}, { $count: "total"}]);
{ "total" : 202 }
```

This is my WIP for selecting comments where up is not smaller than down.

```
> db.comments.aggregate([{ $match: { 'user.id': "1e40v0b1j5"}},{$project: {ratio: {$cond: [{ $gte: [ "$up", "$down" ] }, 1, 0]}}},{$match: {ratio: 1}},{ $count: "positive"}]);
{ "positive" : 77 }
```

Is there a way to combine them in single query?

Comment: I am expecting {positive:2, count: 3}. But if I understand well, your query returns {positive: 2, negative: 1}, does not it? If it is the case, then I can calculcate count in Node.

Comment: but all three are positive because when we check `$up >= $down` look [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4I6zEPGt0pW), can you add expected result if possible.

Comment: This one works like a charm, thank you. Provide is as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both query result in single query using `$group`,

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  { $match: { "user.id": "1eh5mq0qqx" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: 1 },
      positive: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $gte: ["$up", "$down"] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4I6zEPGt0pW)